# rbenv install error on OS X?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

I just upgraded my Mac and updated it using a Time Machine backup that had a fully functioning Ruby package with Rails, Pow and iMagick. For some reason everything seems to be broken.

I am trying to reinstall Ruby using rbenv and get the following message when using `rbenv install 2.1.2`:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks: line 32: cd: ../../../Cellar/rbenv-default-gems/1.0.0/etc/rbenv.d/install: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks: line 32: cd: ../../../Cellar/rbenv-default-gems/1.0.0/etc/rbenv.d/install: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks: line 32: cd: ../../../Cellar/rbenv-default-gems/1.0.0/etc/rbenv.d/install: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv-hooks: line 32: cd: ../../../Cellar/rbenv-default-gems/1.0.0/etc/rbenv.d/install: No such file or directory
```

Any advice on what I can do to fix the problem would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are the files actually there. I had some thing like this in different scenario, turned out to be the files had the "wrong" owner.

Comment: Nope the directory does not exist. I have run `brew install rbenv ruby-build rbenv-gem-rehash` before the install command

Comment: what happens when you run `brew doctor`?

Comment: there are no errors with brew doctor. I think its a gem issue.

Comment: SOLVED So it seems that everything gets a bit messed up when loading from the time machine backup. 

I ran `brew install rbenv-default-gems` and the install was successful.

Comment: When you upgrade an OS you can break existing compiled code that was expecting certain versions of system libraries, or that the paths to files will be what they used to be. Those assumptions often are wrong because version numbers are often used in paths, or routines change names in libraries. I go into a system upgrade expecting to have to recompile Ruby and my gems, and if I don't I consider myself lucky.

Comment: @user3661508 If you’ve solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely. Please don’t only post a comment with the solution.

Comment: I had a similar issue, however the missing gem was not `rbenv-default-gems` like OP. Look at the error and try doing a `brew install` for whatever gem name is in the path it says it cannot find.

Answer (score 1):

Running 'brew prune' should get rid of this issue